# android - Same project cannot run well

Tags: android

I'm developing a simple application which uses Google maps API V2, it all works fine without problems where the map displayed yesterday. Today I uses the exactly the same project, the map cannot be displayed, only the plus and minus symbol.Other parts are all fine.

Besides, it's now getting some error on xml files when i try to change any code on it, such as "Incorrect line ending: found carriage return (\r) without corresponding newline (\n)" . It's totally work fine before this.

I'm still a beginner for all these.Maybe anything wrong with my Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

It does sound like more of an eclipse/line encoding problem then an android problem.

Try opening the file's properties and then under "Resources".
You should see on the right hand side a "Text file encoding" section.
Check that these settings make sense for your platform and project.

More generally speaking, you might also wish to check your eclipse preferences.
Goto: General -> Workspace
There should be a "Text file encoding" and "New Text file line delimiter" sections.

You will want to make sure these are appropriate so this problem doesn't come back

EDIT: After changing these settings you will want to rebuild the problem (aka. Project -> Clean) to make sure it all applied